# How to set bot custom status?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need to set bot custom status. I have tried this code:

```
client.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",  //You can show online, idle....
        game: {
            name: "Using !help",  //The message shown
            type: "STREAMING" //PLAYING: WATCHING: LISTENING: STREAMING:
        }
    });
 });
```

And this:

```
client.user.setActivity('discord.js', { type: 'WATCHING' });
```

And this:

```
client.user.setStatus('available');
    client.user.setActivity(`Using !help`, { //msg shown
    type: "STREAMING",
    url: "" //optional

    });
```

This error shows in console:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Kgt.png)

Now I used this code:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: "Using .help" }, status: "idle" })})
```

But this only sets idle. I need to see text

But nothing work. Can someone help me?

Comment: What's the discord.js version?

Comment: @panzer-chan its 13.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my status code (v13.6 of discord.js):

```
client.user.setActivity('+help', {type: "PLAYING"});
```

The client.on code is as follows:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.setActivity` instead of `.setPresence`, and use this format:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
client.user.setStatus('available');
    client.user.setActivity(`Using !help`, { //msg shown
    type: "STREAMING",
    url: "" //optional

    });
});
```

Comment: its not working sorry. This error shows in console: URL: "" //optional

Comment: @Hadtaw either change STREAMING to something else like PLAYING, or add a random URL. I'm not certain that it can just be left blank.

Comment: Still nothing. When its URL blank its showing error and when i put random link in it still error.

Comment: @Hadtaw i just edited my code. I left out a comma after the type, and url shouldnt be capitalized. Can you try again with those changes?

Comment: Now its good but error its in client.user.setStatus('available'); In setStatus

Comment: @Hadtaw the code I posted is copied directly from my bot that is currently running, so I'm not too sure what issue you are having. Could you update your post with the `client.on('ready')` code, as well as the full error you are receiving?

Comment: @Hadtaw I have updated my post. Try changing `client.on()` to `client.once()`

Comment: Now it not crashed but status its not displayed.

Comment: @Hadtaw This is the exact code I use for my bot and it works without issue, so without seeing all of your code (or at least a large portion of it), it is difficult to tell what the issue may be.

Comment: This code works, but is `available` a valid status? Docs only show `online`, `idle`, etc. Regardless, setting the status to online is not necessary, that is the default status; you can technically remove the `setStatus` line altogether.

Comment: @Cannicide this is working but i dont see status like Using !help

Comment: Well I don't know what to tell you @Hadtaw, the code in this answer is the correct way to set the text of the status. It works perfectly for both myself and the answerer, on the latest version of djs. You probably need to provide more of your code for the answerers to know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('ready', (client) => {
   client.user.setPresence({
       status: "streaming"
   });
});
```

`.setPresence` set your tiny little presence such as `dnd`, `idle`, `online`, `offline`

```
client.user.setActivity({
   type: "STREAMING",
   name: `over ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers.`,
   url: "https://www.twitch.tv/your_twitch_streaming" //optional
});
```

`.setActivity` sets your activity such as `playing`, `watching`, `etc`

I think because its not working on your code files is that, you didn't add `client` after `ready`

You can put them at the same time in your `ready event`

```
client.on('ready', (client) => {
   client.user.setPresence({
       status: "streaming"
   });

client.user.setActivity({
       type: "STREAMING",
       name: `over ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers.`,
       url: "https://www.twitch.tv/your_twitch_streaming" //optional
    });
});
```

Comment: For my bot and every bot I've made, I've always had `client.once('ready', () => {...`, without defining `(client)` like you did. Do you know why that may be the source of the issue, when it has always worked for me?

Comment: What version of d.js are you using anyway?

Comment: This is too not working for me